# Meaning of $\sum\limits_{4}^{0}$

Tags: summation, notation

Encountered this question in Knuth et al's *Concrete mathematics*. The question is:

> What does $\sum\limits_4^0$ mean?

I think it does not mean anything unless we assign it meaning. It's just notation that can mean whatever we want. Maybe a useful meaning would be $\sum\limits_0^4$. This is analogous to scanning a list backwards in programming languages. You can go from 0 to n or n to 0. Does this answer the question?

Comment: This is exercise 2.1 from the book, and the author's solution is in the appendix.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Apparently not. This is amusing... or not.

Answer (score 4):

If one thinks that the additivity property
$$
\sum_i^j+\sum_{j+1}^k=\sum_i^k
$$
is pivotal, one is led to define
$$
\sum_4^0=-\sum_1^3.
$$
More generally, for every integer pair $(i,j)$,
$$
\sum_{i+1}^j=-\sum_{j+1}^i.
$$
**Edit:** The OP now edited their question to explain why, in their opinion, one should use the convention that
$$
\sum_j^k=\sum_k^j
$$
for every $(j,k)$. Naturally, this is another possible option but, as I tried to indicate, it does not serve the same purposes as the one above. Actually, if indeed one chooses this other convention, I would suggest to **avoid altogether** the notation 
$$
\sum_{i=4}^0x_i
$$
and to replace it by something like
$$
\sum_{i\in I}x_i,
$$
where $I=\{4,3,2,1,0\}$, since then the identity $I=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ makes the intended meaning unambiguous.

Comment: How did you derive this formula? The first identity holds for $i\le j$

Comment: Please read on my lips: "If one thinks that the additivity property is pivotal, one is led to..."

Comment: Pivotal also means important :D

Comment: @Did There's something I don't get. If you take $i=j$ in the above formula, this gives $\sum_{i+1}^i=0$.

Comment: @Etienne Good, because $\sum_{i+1}^i=0$ is right.

Comment: @AndreasBlass OK, thanks. This is a little bit disturbing though; especially when compared with the convention for integrals.

Comment: @Etienne The discrepancy with integrals already shows up in situations like this : $\sum_{k=i}^ia_k=a_i$ whereas $\int_m^mf(x)\,dx=0$. $\sum_i^i$ is a sum of one term; $\sum_{i+1}^i$ is the sum of no terms, so it should be zero.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Of course; never forget sums over empty index sets...

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for annoying you again; but $\sum_4^0$ is also the sum of no terms, so it should be $0$ as well ... and yet apparently it is not, according to the law of pivotality of additivity.

Comment: @Did I'm still confused. You should have $0=\sum_2^1=\sum_2^0+\sum_1^1=\sum_1^1$; but this does not seem reasonable.

Comment: $\sum_k^j\equiv \sum_j^k$

Comment: @Etienne Why should one have $\sum\limits_2^0=0$? The interpretation I suggest in my post yields $\sum\limits_2^0x_n=-\sum\limits_1^1x_n=-x_1$, not $0$. Of course, one can also decide that it is more important that $\sum\limits_i^j=0$ for every $i\gt j$, but then one should not ask that additivity holds for every limiting indexes.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=4}^0 k = 4+3+2+1+0=0+1+2+3+4=\sum_{k=0}^4 k$

Comment: @hxthanh Sorry, but what do you think you are achieving with these two comments?

Comment: Get an identity$\displaystyle \sum_{k=a}^b f(k)=\sum_{k=a}^b f(a+b-k)$ i think so

Get $k'=a+b-k$ then $k=a\rightarrow k'=b$ and $k=b\rightarrow k'=a$
Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{k=a}^b f(k)=\sum_{k'=b}^a f(a+b-k')=\sum_{k=a}^b f(a+b-k)$

Comment: @Did You're right, my comment is wrong. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @hxthanh Let me suggest that you read the Edit in my answer, it might help you to ponder things o so slightly.

Comment: @Etienne No problem.

Comment: @Etienne $\sum_4^0$ is not the sum of no terms; it has "even fewer" terms.  $\sum_4^3$ has no terms; $\sum_4^2$ differs from $\sum_4^3$ by lacking term 3; $\sum_4^1$ also lacks term 2; and $\sum_4^0$ also lacks term 1.  So the last of these is minus the sum of terms 1,2,3.

Comment: @Andreas If I understand well, you are (nicely) explaining the law of pivotality of additivity. Now, another question could be: why $\sum_4^3$ has no terms, after all?

Comment: @Etienne Funny how people seem simply to have skipped the first sentence of my post... (While I am at it, there is no "law of pivotality", only a principle (namely, additivity) one can deem important (synonym, pivotal) or not.)

Comment: @Did "Law of pivotality" was a kind of joke. Right now, I'm not quite sure that the additivity principle "should" be preserved. That $\sum_1^0$ is $0$ but $\sum_2^0$ is not is really too confusing, at least for me. Anyway, this is interesting!